# Options dropdown not showing in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Rendering child component and passing all options. The parent component works with the same options. Code sample of the scenario is below the options in the child component are passed from parent component as props

Parent Component

```
    class OptionList extends Component {

  renderUsers() {
    if(this.props.users.length){
    return this.props.users.map(option => (
      <Option options={this.props.options}
      />
    ));
    }
  }

  renderOptionsForm() {
      return (
        <div>

          <form>
            <div className="form-row">
            <Select
              options={this.props.options}
              isMulti
            />
        </div>
          <ul>
            {this.renderUsers()}
          </ul>
      );
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="width-narrow">

        {this.renderOptionsForm()}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
// props
OptionList.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
OptionList.childContextTypes = {
  muiTheme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


// container
export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('options');
  Meteor.subscribe('users');

  return {
    options: Options.find({}).fetch().map(({ name: label, _id: value }) => ({ label, value })),
    users: Users.find().fetch()

  };
})(OptionList);
```

child component

```
    export default class Option extends Component {

  renderEditOptions() {

      return (
        <div>
          <Select
                        options={this.props.options}
                        isMulti
                      />
        </div>
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.renderEditOptions() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here the values are showing correctly but the options dropdown never popups

Comment: do you respect this format ? `const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];`

Comment: Yes. Even i tried copying your options but the dropdown is not coming off.  This works in the parent component

Comment: OK, could you show more code then ? Hard to go further from here

Comment: @GaëlS I have updated my question with the whole code

Comment: @NikhilJacob is the `Client` component the same as the `Option` component or is it different? Because I can´t see the usage of the `Option` component anywhere.

Comment: @Rallen It was a typo. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong prop inside your `Option` component.

The prop you are using (`deliveryTypes`) is not being given to the component. But the `Option` component gets an `options` prop which I assume is the prop you want to use.

```
export default class Option extends Component {
  renderEditOptions() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={this.props.options} // <-- instead of deliveryTypes
          isMulti
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.renderEditOptions() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```